# Where can I find the artwork from the Inkscape: About page?

Tags: inkscape

Clicking Help -> About -> About Inkscape I see this image:

[image]

Where can I find the vector version of this?

Comment: did you checked the repository of the source files here: https://github.com/inkscape/inkscape ?

Comment: @KresimirPendic That doesn't have the source. It tells you to go to another page.

Comment: look here : ) https://i.imgur.com/UktB4BY.png there is a source of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [I found it here](https://github.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/bzr-original/share/screens/about.svg).

If that is not the version of the about screen or Inkscape then I'm afraid you'll need to download the source and look there.

Or, even easier, go to

```
/usr/share/inkscape/screens/about.svg
```

Which has the image from your current version.

Comment: Hmm thats a different version. Looks like they're running an older version on that repo, so I'll look in the source

Comment: @Tim The 0.92x version is [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/0.92.x/view/head:/share/screens/about.svg)

Answer (score 0):

Or find it here: 
https://inkscape.org/~artelnjeru01/%E2%98%85about-092-2-good

This is the original upload from the user who created it, for the Inkscape About Screen contest.